# Get contract address from instantiated ContractRef

Tags: polkadot, ink, smart-contract, pallet-contracts, astar

Based on [this example](https://docs.rs/ink/latest/ink/struct.EnvAccess.html#method.instantiate_contract)

I'm doing something similar:

```
#[ink(message)]
        pub fn new_multisig(&mut self, threshold: u8, owners_list: Vec<AccountId>, salt: Vec<u8>) {
            let multisig = build_create::<MultiSigRef>()
                .code_hash(self.multisig_codehash)
                .gas_limit(0)
                .endowment(0)
                .exec_input(
                    ExecutionInput::new(Selector::new(ink::selector_bytes!("new")))
                        .push_arg(threshold)
                        .push_arg(owners_list),
                )
                .salt_bytes(salt)
                .returns::<MultiSigRef>()
                .instantiate();

            self.env().emit_event(NewMultisig {
                multisig_address: multisig, //Here i need to get the address of the new contract
                threshold: threshold,
                owners_list: owners_list,
            });
        }
```

But I need to obtain the address of the instantiated contract. How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `to_account_id` method to obtain address of instantiated smart contract.

```
use ink::ToAccountId;

let contract_address = multisig.to_account_id();
```

Comment: Hey! That worked, but i also needed to import the trait:

`use ink::ToAccountId;`